# Script to display all IP addresses in a PC and let the user choose the one they want to work with

Tags: vbscript

Good Day,

Please review my code.

I get as far as displaying an inputbox for the user to select the IP address they want to work with, this is for a PC that has more than one NIC running Windows XP. How do I return the chosen IP address in a string format and not the number that corresponds to the selection?

I apologize if I did not post this the right way.

Thank you kindly for your help.

Code Section:

```
Dim longipvalue, a, returnvalueip
strComputer = "."
a=0
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
  & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set IPConfigSet = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
  ("Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration Where IPEnabled=TRUE")
longipvalue = "Please Select the correct IP address for this type of machine" & Chr(10) & Chr(10)
For Each IPConfig in IPConfigSet
  If Not IsNull(IPConfig.IPAddress) Then
    For i=LBound(IPConfig.IPAddress) to UBound(IPConfig.IPAddress)
      a=a+1
      longipvalue = longipvalue & a & ")   " & IPConfig.IPAddress(i) & VbCrLf  & VbCrLf
    Next
  End If
Next
returnvalueip = InputBox (longipvalue)
MsgBox returnvalueip
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you.
Concatenate the addresses, then split, and show the user's selection...

```
Dim longipvalue, a, returnvalueip
Dim ipAddr  'Concatenate all IP addresses with "|"

strComputer = "."
a=0
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
  & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set IPConfigSet = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
  ("Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration Where IPEnabled=TRUE")
longipvalue = "Please Select the correct IP address for this type of machine" & Chr(10) & Chr(10)

ipAddr = ""
For Each IPConfig in IPConfigSet
  If Not IsNull(IPConfig.IPAddress) Then
    For i=LBound(IPConfig.IPAddress) to UBound(IPConfig.IPAddress)
      a=a+1
      longipvalue = longipvalue & a & ")   " & IPConfig.IPAddress(i) & VbCrLf  & VbCrLf
      'Concatenate
      ipAddr = ipAddr & IPConfig.IPAddress(i) & "|"
    Next
  End If
Next

returnvalueip = InputBox (longipvalue)

' Show IP Address chosen
MsgBox Split(ipAddr, "|")(returnvalueip - 1)
```